# Cannot register svg icon

Tags: svg, angular-material2, angular5

I would like to register a new Material2 icon, I have this code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-control-panel',
  templateUrl: './control-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./control-panel.component.scss']
})

export class ControlPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    console.log('registering  play button icon');  // << confirm

    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('play_button',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/play-button.svg'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

the log statement above is being hit. And I have this HTML

```
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
    <mat-icon>play_button</mat-icon>
    Start Recording
  </button>
```

if I use an existing icon it works, but if I use "play_button" it doesn't work.

Anyone know what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `<mat-icon>` should set the `svgIcon` property. i.e.:
   `<mat-icon svgIcon="play_button"></mat-icon>`
2. `MatIconRegistry` should be imported from `@angular/material`
3. Ensure that you import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts` so the asset you're requesting can be downloaded.